# Advantages/disadvantages of Morita over Tu

Tags: differential-geometry, reference-request, manifolds, book-recommendation, characteristic-classes

I plan on studying manifolds and differential geometry.

I have heard good things about Morita's *Geometry of Differential Forms/Characteristic Classes* and Tu's *Introduction to Manifolds/Differential Geometry*.

However, I do wonder about the pedagogical/topic coverage advantages/disadvantages between both pairs of books.

Thus I am looking for an honest comprasion between the two pairs.

For example, would it be better if I choose one pair to study and find more advanced references for topics not present in the chosen pair but in the other pair(example, Hodge theory in Morita, but not in Tu, etc.)?

Perhaps one may also mention which pair of books have their errors/typos corrected/have less errors and typos(Tu's Manifolds 2nd edition has a 3 page errata PDF on Google, whereas Morita's errata PDF is nowhere to be found, if ti exists).

My background is linear and abstract algebra, point set and algebraic topology(Hatcher), analysis from Robert Gunnig's MAT 218 notes, and classical differential geometry from O'Neill.

Suggestions for books not mentioned here based off of my background/other consideratoins are welcome!